# What colour is the dark green on 'old fashioned' green screen computer displays/VDUs?

Tags: display, colors

I'd like to make my text editors display like the old skool white-on-green VDUs of yore that I can just about remember from my childhood. I have this idea they might be easier on my old eyes.

I was wondering if there was standard dark green used on these and, if so, what the RGB or Hex values for it might be?

Comment: Similar Question on Retro Computing Stack Exchange: [*Exactly what color was the text on monochrome terminals with green-on-black and amber-on-black screens?*](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12835/851)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

DaveBoltman's answer is very remarkable and useful. However, the phosphors' wavelengths in Wikipedia are not exact. There are other references and Google books giving slightly different values. For instance, P1 w/l is 525, not 528 nm:
http://www.labguysworld.com/crt_phosphor_research.pdf

Anyway, I remember what colors those phosphors displayed (including the amber phosphors), so I am nearly sure of these RGB and Hex values:

[image]

I suppose that Apple //c and Apple /// monitors used the P24 GE phosphor, because they had its hue. And the background of the old monochrome CRTs usually was lighter than pure black, see this photo:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/IBM_PC_5150.jpg]

For better eye comfort, I suggest that the OP use any of those greens with that background. In the dark, the old-fashioned green on dark gray looks better than the present black on white.

Comment: It's funny after all this time, eyes feel better with basic combination of ambar or green on black. Just created iTerm2 profile based on your answer. Good stuff, thank you

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by `hex color #XXXXXX = YYY nm`, as that certainly doesn't make sense as an equation.  The real-life color produced by some RGB color will depend highly on the display.  Which was the original and how did you derive the other from it?

Comment: incidentally, for historical reasons or not, amber and green on "black" are used in most modern arliner cockpit instruments and displays. They are mostly bright text on dark background. And you can imagine the variance of ambient light conditions in an aircraft cockpit, and the split-timing decisions that need to be made after noticing a certain light signal

Answer (score 27):

Inspired by the below (incomplete) answers:

1. Almost all the "'old fashioned' green screen computer displays/VDUs" used the P1 phosphor (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome_monitor) reference)
2. The P1 phosphor produces a peak wavelength (a.k.a. colour in human terms) of 528 nm ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor#Standard_phosphor_types))
3. Converting colour from a wavelength to RGB values (in the commonly used byte format of 0 to 255) using formulae [here](http://www.midnightkite.com/color.html), gives: Red=65   Green=255   Blue=0, or **#41FF00** in hexadecimal. (see [this convertor](http://lsrtools.1apps.com/wavetorgb/index.asp?wavelength=528)).
4. This does not take brightness into account. (to adjust the brightness the RBG value would need to be converted to HSV, have the V component adjusted up or down, then converted back to RGB to satisfy the OP).

Answer (score 11):

- There wasn't a standard color.
- Brightness is part of color and was usually changeable by turning a knob.
- Colors change as the phosphor ages.
- You could order VDUs with amber and other color phosphors.
- Some makers claimed amber was better for eyes.
- The ones I used were mostly green on black (not white on green)
- RGB values probably depend on calibration of your display.

Comment: "Some makers claimed amber was better for eyes." - Medically-prescribed 'VDU' glasses were/are amber-tinted (a relative worked in a medical eye centre)

Comment: in short. do what a lot of nostalgic geeks do, and adjust it till it *looks* right

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really remember what it looked like. I was <10yrs old at the time :-|

Comment: I've tried both amber and green.  In hindsight I liked the amber best.

Answer (score 9):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor#Standard_phosphor_types) you can find a wavelength of this phosphor and RGB conversion formulas can be found easily from internet.

Comment: Wow! Now that's what I *call* a geeky answer. Many, many thanks for this amazing idea!

Answer (score -3):

Try RGB color code:

```
R:36
G:204
B:68
```

For a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is the right color? Other answers provide some insight and reasoning. How can we tell it's not just your opinion or a wild guess?